# Position of volitional form and scope of かな ending

Tags: grammar, sentence-final-particles, volitional-form, modality

Referring to throwing away old clothes to improve your life:

> この中のいくらかを捨てて、スッキリしてみよう**かな**。
>   Maybe I will throw some of them away and try feeling refreshed.

My translation is a bit silly.

1) Does かな act on the whole sentence or just the second clause, i.e does she wonder if throwing clothes away will make her feel refreshed or does she wonder about the act of throwing away the clothes too?

2) I don't really understand してみよう here. Presumably this is the volitional form of してみる (I will try to doing ...). But, you don't normally 'try to feel refreshed'; it sounds weird.

I'd like to move てみよう to the end of the first clause so that I get "I will try throwing some of them away, and maybe I'll feel refreshed", but then I don't think you can add a second clause, because 捨ててみよう can't be turned into て形 can it? Is that why it all has to move to the end of the second clause?

Comment: I think in this case she has had the experience of cleaning up the storage, so she knows that cleaning them up make the storage look tidy and it would likely to make her refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking about is only applicable to the English translation and the original Japanese sentence is free from that doubt because the latter has only one predicate that can form a sentence (i.e みよう) while the former has two of "throw away" and "feel refreshed".

1) You can't interpret it as "she wonder if throwing away clothes makes her feel refreshed" because してみよう stands for her own will, which is questioned with か（な）. In other words, if it was 捨ててスッキリするかな, that interpretation would be possible too.

2) Compared with simple してみる, してみよう is more or less motivating yourself to do it when it feels reluctant. So, してみようかな sounds a little more uncertain if the speaker does it.

p.s I find "この中のいくらかを" is a way of thinking that is unique to people whose language is developed in the field of number.

Comment: Thanks. In that case perhaps I don't understand スッキリする properly. I don't understand how you can 'feel refreshed' with volition. Saying 'I intend to feel refreshed (by doing something)' in English is really weird. Is there another translation of スッキリする  that would make this sound more natural?